# Term for administration of a university

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a collective term for the senior administration of a university (dean and upwards)?

I am looking for something specific to the U.S., though not specific to a particular system (such as *regents* for the University of California).

Comment: I think "senior administration" works very well as a collective term.

Comment: Yes many - but unfortunately all are unsuitable for a family website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use terms like **directors** or **leaders**, however **senior administration** is a quite accurate description.  You could also consider **senior staff**.